# AWS - Print details on instance that the lambda launches

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and have been creating some scripts for automation.

This script is launching an EC2 instance. What I would like it to do is also return and print the 'instance ID' and 'public IP' of the instance that the code itself is launching.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # create a new EC2 instance
    instances = ec2.create_instances(
     ImageId='ami-*******',
     MinCount=1,
     MaxCount=1,
     InstanceType='t2.micro',
     KeyName='*****'
     )

    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky bit here is that public IP may be **not immediately available** after execution of `create_instances`. Thus to overcome this timing problem, you can implement basic while loop to wait for the IP.

```
import json
from time import sleep

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2r = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    instances = ec2.create_instances(
         ImageId='ami-0c94855ba95c71c99',
         MinCount=1,
         MaxCount=1,
         InstanceType='t2.micro',
         KeyName='xxxxxxx'
    )
    
    instance = instances[0]
    
    while instance.public_ip_address is None:
        print('Wait 2 seconds and check again for public ip')
        sleep(2)
        instance = ec2r.Instance(instance.instance_id)

    print('Public IP available')
    
    return [instance.instance_id, instance.public_ip_address]
```

Comment: Thanks! It did actually return the Public IP immediately, which is great. I'm trying to set up VM's for employees so they don't need to access AWS themselves, this way I can create an API which returns their login info for the Teradici client.